# How to uninstall another package before installing current one with dpkg?

Tags: apt, deb, dpkg, cydia

I need to uninstall another package before current package being installed, I tried put `dpkg --remove  com.foo.foo.another` in `preinst` file, which doesn't work, it throws error `dpkg: error: dpkg status database is locked by another process`. How can I achieve that? Appreciate!

Comment: `com.foo.foo.another` isn't a valid package name anyway. If you are actually trying to remove a Java file which wasn't installed by `dpkg`, you need to remove it by whatever means Java offers.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that. Dpkg locks its database for the whole process of installation - none of your scripts will be able to do anything like installing or uninstalling a package.

I had a similar problem. I wanted to install debian package manually during installation of my app. My app had a daemon which I launched as part of installation. To solve my problem in the daemon I waited until dpkg releases the lock and then installed the package. It's very important that I did it in a daemon as it's detached from `postinst` script, so dpkg can happily finish the installation.

You probably need to do something similar.

Comment: Removing the conflicting package *before* you install yours might make more sense. If you have control over the package you're installing, put `Conflicts: otherpackage` in its `debian/control` file before building it.

Comment: @tripleee, thank you, but it doesn't work even I put `Conflicts:com.xxx.xxx` or `Conflicts: xxx` in `control` file, it still threw conflict error while installing.

Comment: @Suge As indicated elsewhere, `com.xxx.xxx` is almost certainly not the name of a valid package. Do you have a installed package whose name is `xxx`?

Comment: @tripleee Yes, there is a package named xxx installed before. In fact this is a tweak project built for jailbroke iOS devices, you know, jailbreak development uses `dpkg` system to manage installation, the rules should be same. But `Conflicts` keyword looks invalid, don't know why.

Comment: "Looks invalid" how? This is documented in the policy manual: https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html#s-conflicts

Comment: @tripleee on iOS we use reverse dns scheme to name Debian packages. Usually it matches bundle identifier of the application